# Hibernate optimization, use second level cache?

Tags: hibernate, caching, optimization

I am developing a database access and persistance layer based in Hibernate. The application that must use the hibernate module must execute very complex queries with multiple joins.

I must recommend items based on the items bought by other customers, so it's difficult to store in cache specific data, since a recommendation is concrete and the percentage of cache misses will be very high.

I have tested the performance and I have observed that all works very slow, I use Mysql 5, Hibernate 4 and C3P0 connection provider. Should I use a second level Hibernate cache system based on EHCACHE? Is Memcached a good solution? Is there any other way to improve Hibernate performance?

Thank you for your advice and help.

Answer (score 0):

First check the query's performance via a direct SQLClient tool. If it performs bad, tune it up. 
Now, if you plan to use caching for reference data alone (mostly read only) EHCache is a good choice. If you want to use caching for transactional data, JBOSS Tree Cache is a good option.

Comment: I have optimized the query as much as I could. If I test the query in Mysql Workbench it runs slow but not as slow as in Hibernate. The problem is thart caching a recommendation is not easy.

Comment: use explain option prepended to your select query to see and analyze the execution plan from mysql workbench. Example: explain select * from user where id = 5; Do you see the access using indexed columns?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know this Mysql feature. Thank You. But I'm no Mysql expert and I don't know which parameters I should look at to improve the query. I can see in the extra colum the indexes that are being used.